# How to cast a string date yyyy/MM/dd into MMMM dd, yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm a little bit puzzled on how to do this...

I have tried `DateTime.Parse()` with this code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(body[j],"yyyy/MM/dd",null).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")
```

(where `body[j]` is and array of strings)

But still, the resulting string output is `yyyy/MM/dd`

Anybody who could tell me how to fix this?
Or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is not going to change the contents of `body[j]`.  It will return a new `string` containing the date in the new format.  If you want `body[j]` to contain that new `string` then you have to assign it, i.e.

```
body[j] = DateTime.ParseExact(body[j],"yyyy/MM/dd",null).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy");
```

Comment: still no luck...still the same output.
there might be something wrong with my `ParseExact()`???

Comment: There can't anything wrong with your `ParseExact` call.  Either it returns a `DateTime` value or it throws an exception.  Presumably you would know if it was throwing an exception but maybe you should confirm that it's not.  Maybe you should should show us the actual code you're using and show/explain how you're testing the output.  If you were doing it right then it would be working.

Comment: I'm so sorry, the code is right..It's just my code's condition (if/else) that has the problem..

Thanks a lot!!!! :D

Comment: oh wait...I receive an error..

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `body[j]` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Hi sir @jmcilhinney, I've fixed it, just used `String.Trim()` to remove unwanted character..Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are evaluating this as the following gives me October 12,2005 as the result

```
var str= DateTime.ParseExact("2005/10/12","yyyy/MM/dd",null).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Please check your array values properly